# What to do with users who aren't voting or accepting answers

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

Over at math.SE (where I'm a moderator) we've been having problems with a user who isn't voting or accepting answers to questions. This seems completely against the spirit of the site, but I'm not sure to what extent it's my responsibility to make sure that users do this. What's the general opinion on this?

Answer (score 9):

Yes this is against the spirit of the site, however we already display the "Mark of Cain" on near their avatar showing the accept rate.

Lack of voting is highlighted both on their profile and the new https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters page.

One of our most [important/influential users](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) on Stack Overflow almost **never** votes.

I think that as a moderator you should look at each problem holistically.

1. Is the user contributing good content to the site?
2. Is the user a positive influence?

And so on...

For example: I would never contact Eric asking him to start voting, he does plenty to make our site awesome.

However, a serial asker that asks average to bad questions and never accepts may get the boot.

Comment: The user is clearly just asking homework questions and it is getting very annoying. But I want a clear guideline I can point at to say "you should stop doing this."

Comment: @Qiaochu I am not privy to the particular case, but at SO if a user is a serial homework question asker they would probably be banned automatically from asking questions ... in the past we have banned and contacted these kind of users

Comment: I'd love to know which post earned Eric's single upvote.

Comment: @SamSaffron & anyone else who is associated: What do we do as a non-moderator if we come upon a user like this? Can we flag their profile for it?