# Should I flag user profiles for users who are posting tons of questions and accepting no answers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, accept-rate

I've come across profiles where people are actively participating on S.O. by posting answers, yet have an absolute 0 percent acceptance rate on all their questions. Typically I try to post a comment on one of their questions to encourage them to review their history and accept some answers, but rarely are the people responsive. So my question is, should I flag these profiles for a mod to review? I know that might sound overkill, and I'm not thinking of "getting them in trouble", but rather getting a message across to them in the most effective manner.

I find this to be an issue that warrants this type of intervention, because having the site filled up with tons of orphaned questions seems to be counterproductive to me. For me personally, when I'm searching through the Q/A's for a solution, the first thing I look for (after confirming the topic to be relative to my situation of course) is the green highlight over the question indicating that a valid solution was found in this post. I'm sure others do the same.

Again just to be clear I'm not talking about militantly chasing down new users and freezing their accounts and telling them to participate correctly "or else" or anything crazy, and I'm not talking about accounts with a few rep, which is a clear indication they're a very new user and are still most likely figuring things out. The latest profile I found is 500+ rep with a 0% accept rate on 5 questions.

P.S. I am aware of [this question and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82092/what-to-do-with-users-who-arent-voting-or-accepting-answers), but the answer provided doesn't answer my question specifically. :)

Comment: I'd like to ask drive-by downvoters to kindly give the reason for your downvoting. I can't possibly see what could be "negative" about asking a question about how to correctly go about trying to improve the quality of the site. But hey, that would be a fantastic reason to leave a comment explaining yourself right? Drive by downvoting it kind of like disciplining your child without explanation. The offender is doomed to repeat (if your point is even valid, of course). :)

Comment: You had exactly one vote when you posted that comment. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @Josh Caswell ah, I see. Thanks for pointing that out. I don't really use meta much, didn't realize the voting system had a different meaning here. :) Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Votes work differently on Meta: They are used to voice disagreement, not necessarily a low quality contribution. I, for example, think this is a perfectly fine question, but my answer is "no, you shouldn't flag them because asking only questions is fine as long as they're not all *bad* questions", which is why I also downvoted. (Edit: ah, @Josh beat me to the punch)

Comment: Even if you're just offering a topic for discussion, votes will go one way or the other, depending on the phrasing of the question (i.e., "Should I do this?"/"Should I not do this?").

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think users like that should be flagged.

If nothing else, a moderator can't really do much in this case that you can't already do.

We're likely going to just leave a comment and call it done, and in most cases even leaving a comment isn't necessary. Accepting answers is not mandatory, so we might leave a polite reminder once but there's really no need to try to enforce something that's optional in the first place.